# Дырки в QGraphicsProxyWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

При изменении положения слайдера в QSlider и редактировании значения в QSpinBox в виджетах появляются дырки(прозрачные полосы в фоне).
Подскажите пожалуйста как этого избежать.
Cцена увеличена:

```
scale(1.6, 1.6);
```

И у виджета меняется позиция:

```
prepareGeometryChange();  
setPos( pos );
```

[image: Дырки в QGraphicsProxyWidget]

Answer (score 1):

Проблема была в использовании кэша:

```
setCacheMode(QGraphicsItem::DeviceCoordinateCache);
```

Без него, всё правильно.